# scrolling with velocity.js doesn't scroll

Tags: javascript, velocity.js

I can't get it to work. I've added it via CDN and a code snippet for smooth scrolling in app.js straight from an example from the author to be sure I got it right. Clicking on my link takes me nowhere.

```
<li class="active"><a href="#footer">Contact</a></li>
```

...html

```
<footer class="footer" id="footer">
```

...html

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/foundation/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/velocity/1.2.2/velocity.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/velocity/1.2.2/velocity.ui.min.js"></script>
```

//app.js

```
  $("#footer").velocity("scroll", { 
  duration: 800,
  delay: 500
});
```

Comment: What is "nowhere"? Do you see an error in the console? Are you sure there's enough content in the page to scroll anything? A full example in a jsFiddle would be better.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. This was my first post to SE. I'll try to clarify when I get a few minutes. Also "nowhere" = <a href="#">. Clicking does nothing.